# RecycleView pagination not adding new item at the end?

Tags: java, android, pagination, adapter

I am getting data from the server through web service and showing in recycle view.Every request I am getting 5 item from the server. I debug my code and checked that when I scroll to end of recycleview then new data is getting from the server but it's not adding in the end of recycleview. How can I solve that?

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_timeline);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        listView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        listView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        //Adding an scroll change listener to recyclerview
        listView.setOnScrollChangeListener(this);

        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(this);
        isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

        db = new SQLiteHandler(this);

        // session manager
        session = new SessionManager(this);

        /*pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MayahudiPref", 0);
        editor = pref.edit();*/

        // Fetching user details from sqlite
        HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();
        id = user.get("id");
        token = user.get("token");


        getData();



        adapter = new TimeLineListAdapter(timeLineItems, this);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void getTimeLineData(final String token, final String page) {

        timeLineItems = new ArrayList<>();

            String tag_string_req = "req_register";
            // making fresh volley request and getting json
            StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.timeline, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                    if (response != null) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("status");
                            String message = jObj.getString("message");
                            if(error){
                                totalPages = jObj.getInt("totalPages");
                                pageCount = jObj.getInt("page");

                                int limit = jObj.getInt("limit");
                                parseJsonFeed(response);
                            }

                        }catch (Exception e){

                        }

                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                }
            }) {

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    // Posting params to register url
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("my_token", token);
                    params.put("page", page);
                    params.put("limit", "5");

                    return params;
                }
            };

            // Adding request to request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);

    }

    private void parseJsonFeed(String response) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray feedArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                TimeLineItem item = new TimeLineItem();
                item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
                item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));
                item.setLname(feedObj.getString("lname"));

                // Image might be null sometimes
                String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("image");
                item.setImge(image);
                item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("story_text"));
                item.setProfilePic(feedObj.getString("profile_pic"));
                item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("time_stamp"));
                item.setIsLike(feedObj.getInt("is_like"));
                item.setTotalLikes(feedObj.getString("total_likes"));
                item.setTotalComment(feedObj.getString("total_comments"));

                /*// url might be null sometimes
                String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("url");
                item.setUrl(feedUrl);*/

                timeLineItems.add(item);
            }

            // notify data changes to list adapater
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //This method will get data from the web API
    private void getData() {
        //Adding the method to the queue by calling the method getDataFromServer
        getTimeLineData(token , String.valueOf(requestCount));
        //Incrementing the request counter
        requestCount++;
    }

    //This method would check that the recyclerview scroll has reached the bottom or not
    private boolean isLastItemDisplaying(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        if (recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() != 0) {
            int lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            if (lastVisibleItemPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && lastVisibleItemPosition == recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1)

                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
        //Ifscrolled at last then
        if (isLastItemDisplaying(listView)) {
            //Calling the method getdata again
            getData();
        }
    }
```

Comment: use like : if (page==0){ timeLineItems = new ArrayList<>(); }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you create a new items list each time you call `getTimeLineData()`:

```
timeLineItems = new ArrayList<>();
```

First check if you already have a list:

```
if (timeLineItems == null) {
    timeLineItems = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks mrsegev. Solved my prob.

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to upvote, accept answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
RecylerView article_list;


article_list.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            visibleitemcount = linearLayoutManager.getChildCount();
            total_itemcount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            pastVisiblecount = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            Log.d(TAG, "Total : " + total_itemcount + "Visible : " + visibleitemcount + "Past : " + pastVisiblecount);
            if (loading) {
                if (visibleitemcount + pastVisiblecount >= total_itemcount) {
                    loading = false;
                    getHealthyLivingfromUrl(5, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    });


private void getHealthyLivingfromUrl(int limit, int offset) {

            //get the data code
       article_list.setAdapter(articleAdapter);
                        if (total_itemcount!=0 && total_itemcount > visibleitemcount) {
                            linearLayoutManager.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);
                            linearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(total_itemcount-visibleitemcount);
                        }
                        loading = true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using POST method to obtain data ? Everytime you obtaining data you are creating new array, onCreate you assign to adapter an array. Then you create one, but no assign. I think you should create in adapter class, addItems(List items) method and every time you are getting data you use this method (inside this method you can notifi data has changed). That's all.